# unset $_POST doesn't works

Tags: php, post, xdebug

Here is my code
http://pastebin.com/DtK8MMtU
when user pressing 'Next turn' button, $_POST["turnOver"] is getting set. Then script goes into this section

```
 if (isset($_POST["turnOver"])) {
                $_SESSION["state"] = 0;
                unset($_SESSION["rolls"] );
                unset($_SESSION["bet"]);
                unset($_SESSION["nextTurn"]);
                $_SESSION["turnNumber"]++;
                unset($_POST["turnOver"]);    
 }
```

By this row `unset($_POST["turnOver"]);` i want this block executes only once after user pressed 'Next turn' button, but this executed every time user refreshed page (i saw this by $_SESSION["turnNumber"] value, its increasing all the time i refresh page). Also, here is  $_POST var_dump from xdebug:

```
array (size=1)
  'turnOver' => string ''... (length=9)
```

It means it is set?

Comment: You can't do that. You could, however, check if `$_SESSION["state"]` is not 0, and if it already it, don't execute. When you UNSET it's only for the rest of the execution of the PHP script. Meaning if you try to access `$_POST["turnOver"]` after that, then it'd fail as you removed it from the array, but it's resubmitted on every refresh.

Comment: You could include a random number with every legitimate post. Store that number in a session variable. Check that the number given is not the same as the one that is stored.  If it is the same then it is a browser refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user is refreshing the page they will be sending the `turnOver` POST value each time. Unsetting post will only affect the rest of that page.

Best thing to do is set a session value and set that the first time that `turnOver` is sent then check against that.

Comment: Actually, just thinking out loud here: Couldn't he send a 302 header (`header("Location: thisurl.php");`) and avoid the whole refreshing problem?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Good point. It's good practice to redirect after a post to prevent this kind of thing.

Comment: Alternatively, he could store a unique form key in the session, only consider the form as submitted when matched, and generate a new form key when the submission is accecpted. This is regularly used to prevent duplicate submissions.

Answer (score 2):

You said

> I saw this by $_SESSION["turnNumber"] value, its increasing all the time i refresh page

This is a normal beauvoir since you execute

```
$_SESSION["turnNumber"]++;
```

which will keep adding 1 at each refresh. Further more before the line

```
unset($_POST["turnOver"]);
```

Your `$_POST["turnOver"]` is actually set so if you try a var_dump before the unset() command you will see it as set.

Comment: so, even if i unset($_POST["turnOver"]), its being set automatically when i refresh page, even if i dont press button which sets it?

Comment: yes if you refresh you will repost the data and $_POST["turnOver"] will be available in post array untill you actually execute the unset()